# TailwindCSS is not working after installation

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have followed and installed TailwindCSS from this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

I have created a new test project and I add some code to index.html, but when I run it it does not apply TailwindCSS styles.

Here is the project structure with index.html file.

[image]

Here is the content of tailwind.config.js file:

```
   module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I am using this command:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Here is my input.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

After I run the app, everything is white and without changing text style, but as you can see from the code, the background should be blue and bigger text.

[image]

Where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Your `index.html` file is within `src` folder. Change path to styles into `../dist/output.css` or move `index.html` into the project root (out of `src` directory)

Comment: How to change the styles path? Can you post answer and I will accept it if it works fine?

Comment: In your HTML head section like `<link href="../dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: i have tried to move index.hmlt out of src directory, but it does not work.

Comment: If you moved index file, the path should be `./dist/output.css`, otherwise it will look this file at the root of your system. You may look at inspector what does it tell about `output.css` file (where does site cannot locate styles. which path is it). I'm almost positive this is relative path issue

Comment: Wow, thanks Ihar. It worked after fixing my issue with HTML head section. Can you post your answer and I will accept it? The funny thing is that I have copy and pasted code from official documentation and they have this issue there.

Comment: It depends on environment, on a real web-server absolute path will work. as root server directory will be the project directory itself. Glad it helped that's enough for me)

Answer (score 0):

Edit content value of module in tailwind.config.js file like:

```
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
```

Remember go to output.css file then ctrl + S to save it.

Comment: I have done it, but it still does not work. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the `input.css` file, make sure that the last two tailwind utilities are at bottom, like this

```
@tailwind base;

html,body {
...
}


@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: I have those. I have updated my question with that file. Do you have other ideas?